# Structural pattern matching in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to parse some open-source code of Python to check if the source contains some specific patterns.

For example:

```
for i in range...:
    if(i == 2):
    .......
```

I might want to find if the source code contains a pattern just like above: an if statement inside a for loop. I know the expression pattern matching technique, but it does not work for this case.

Does anyone know how to find this kind of pattern matching automatically? Any useful tool?

Comment: Take a look at the `ast` module, it will parse Python code and return a tree representation of it.

Comment: Yes, I tried AST module. I can detect where a loop is, but I can not detect a for loop with an if statement inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ast.parse()`.

```
import ast

code = '''
for i in range(1, 10):
    if (i == 2):
        print(i)
'''
parsed = ast.parse(code)
for stmt in parsed.body:
    if isinstance(stmt, ast.For):
        for stmt2 in stmt.body:
            if isinstance(stmt2, ast.If):
                print("Found if in for")
                break
```

This example is very simple, it only looks for `for` at the top level of the code, and `if` at the second level. You should be able to extend it to a recursive solution that searches for nested constructs.